# HP charger burnt?

Tags: laptop, power-supply

Ok so I got a new HP laptop around a month ago and today I was watching Netflix and my battery was 10%. So I went downstairs and got my charger and when I plugged it in it wasn't working. I thought the outlet had a problem so I tried one downstairs and it still wasn't charging and then I smelled something burning.

I checked my charger and yeah for sure there was a burning smell coming from it. It seems to have been burnt and I don't know what to do.

Comment: Contact HP Now, they will resolve it, you have a warranty and HP takes this type of problem seriously. Disconnect charger from wall socket and don't use it!

Comment: Is the power cord a Linetek LS-15? https://h30652.www3.hp.com/

Comment: To be honest I have no clue, anyway I would be able to find out

Comment: @AnuArora From the link "Potentially affected power cords can be identified by a molded mark on the adapter end of the power cord. The molded mark will be “LS-15”." Look at the photo referenced in the link.

Comment: @AnuArora If the computer is a month old and new (not new-to-you), it's not part of that recall. That recall is from 2014 for components sold in from 2010 to 2012.

Answer (score 5):

If the machine is new (rather than new-to-you) and only a month old, it should still be covered under warranty. You need to contact [HP Worldwide Limited Warranty and Technical Support](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/privacy/limited_warranty.html). They may be able to replace just the power supply, but they may want to swap out the entire machine. Contacting them directly is the only way to be sure.

In the interim, if you absolutely must use the machine and you are confident the problem is not in the computer itself, you can purchase first-party (made by HP) or third-party (not made by HP) power adapters in most big-box electronics retailers. Availability of first-party power adapters can vary widely in small Mom'n'Pop type retailers.

Whatever you do, **do NOT plug a suspect power supply into ANYTHING**.

Answer (score 0):

ok my problem is that I was watching youtube and it was charging and when I plugged it on it dint work what should I do rather than exchange it for hp and its new about a half month old now